# How to add several Locators to a Graphic with a mouse click?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, manipulate

**Background:** Suppose I have something like this:

```
 DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0, 0}, pt2 = {0, 1}, pt3 = {1, 0}},
  Graphics[Polygon[{pt1, pt2, pt3}], PlotRange -> 1]]
```

which I would like to change into this via a mouse click on the `Polygon` into this:

```
 DynamicModule[
  {pt1 = {0, 0}, pt2 = {0, 1}, pt3 = {1, 0}},
  Manipulate[
   Graphics[Polygon[{pt1, pt2, pt3}], PlotRange -> 1],
   {{pt1, {0, 0}}, Locator}, {{pt2, {0, 1}}, Locator}, {{pt3, {1, 0}}, 
    Locator}]]
```

**Question:** What code should I add to one of the snippets above to achieve this?

Comment: You could see this question and its answers: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/how-to-interactively-create-a-polygon-in-a-graphic

Comment: FJRA, I know, I asked the question myself. I am still learning Dynamic, it is hard but I am getting there with your help. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't noticed it's you :P. Anyway it's good to have the link as reference for anyone who lands in this related question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions. In both cases, one click brings locators up, another click will make them disappear.

## Solution 1

Using multiple *dynamic* locators. The `Map` (or `/@`) is needed, since `Dynamic` inside `Locator` should have evaluated part number for `pts`.

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, locs = {}}, 
 Graphics[{EventHandler[
    Polygon[Dynamic[
      pts]], {"MouseClicked" :> (locs = 
        If[locs === {}, 
         Locator[Dynamic[pts[[#]]]] & /@ Range[Length[pts]], {}])}], 
   Dynamic[locs]}, PlotRange -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]]
```

A slightly weird behavior of locators (washed out color when it appears first)... which I don't know why.

## Solution 2

Using [`LocatorPane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html). Simpler, but `Dynamic` needs to refresh both `locPts` and `pts` when `locs` is assigned ([`Dynamic[expr, f]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) syntax).

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}}, locPts = {}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[locPts, (If[locPts =!= {}, pts = locPts = #]) &], 
  Graphics[{EventHandler[
     Polygon[Dynamic[
       pts]], {"MouseClicked" :> (locPts = If[locPts === {}, pts, {}])}]},
    PlotRange -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]]]]
```

Comment: Sorry, I upped your answer, but I forgot to accept. Thanks again for your excellent answer. ( The fog that hang over DynamicModule is -finally- beginning to fade! )