# Editable keyframe curves

Tags: plotting

Any suggestions for a good approach to implementing a zoomable 'keyframe' based curve editor? Essentially, something akin to the functionality of the graph editor in animation packages such as Maya. (see [here](http://www.imanishi.com/mayablog_en/2008/07/maya-tutorialthe-graph-editor.html)).

I can see how to get started on something simple using Locators, but the ability to zoom and pan on long time ranges is something that looks tricky to me, and I suspect starting out with the right concept in the first place will save a lot of headaches...any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html#94935826) as a starting point.

Comment: Maybe a concept like [InteractiveTradingChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InteractiveTradingChart.html) ?

Comment: Heike's interactive curve drawing machine: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4179/how-to-interactively-create-a-polygon-in-a-graphic/4183

Comment: zooming and panning perhaps covered here:http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/57

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be under the impression that writing an interface like that in *Mathematica* takes a lot of time. In fact *Mathematica* is a very good tool for rapid prototyping of such interfaces, and it's often fruitful not to think about how much time one could potentially waste and just try it.

I believe that your question about zoom and panning has already been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21583/how-to-zoom-and-pan-a-listlineplot). The key to both zooming and panning is to control `PlotRange`. This can be done in different ways. Below is a very simple example and the link provides more advanced methods. I'm using `LocatorPane` as was suggested in the comments. `Interpolate` finds the curve that ties the locators together:

```
Manipulate[
 LocatorPane[
  Dynamic[pts],
  Dynamic@Plot[
    InterpolatingPolynomial[pts, x], {x, offset, offset + width},
    PlotRange -> {{offset, offset + width}, {0, 10}}
    ],
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True
  ],
 {{offset, 0, "Offset"}, 0, 50},
 {{width, 10, "Width"}, 1, 50},
 Initialization :> (
   pts = {{0, 0}};
   )
 ]
```

[image: example]