# How to zoom and pan a ListLinePlot?

Tags: plotting, front-end

I'm using `ListLinePlot` inside a `Manipulate` function to display some data.

I've seen that *Mathematica* allows [zooming and panning](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/RotateZoomAndPanGraphics.html) but it's either only for 3D plots or it just doesn't work with `ListLinePlot`.

I've also seen a thread [here on Stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots) for a custom function to zoom and pan but it doesn't seem to work when I apply it to `ListLinePlot` (error message "... is not a graphics primitive or directive").

So is there a solution I've missed to be able to zoom and pan a `ListLinePlot`?

Comment: As far as I know, the builtin mouse-zoom/pan/rotate/etc. only works for 3D graphics. There are domestic community solutions though, see these threads: [manipulating plots in 2D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7142/89), [zooming in 2D](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jan/msg00009.html), [panning in 2D](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7019/89).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, the following works within a `Manipulate`-`ListLinePlot` environment:

```
   Clear[x0];
    Manipulate[


     Grid[{{ListLinePlot[
         Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}],
         Epilog -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.1], 
            Rectangle[{x0 - \[Delta], -1.1}, {x0 + \[Delta], 1.1}]}}], 
        "Full Plot"},

       {ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}], 
         Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, 
         Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
         PlotRange -> {{x0 - \[Delta], x0 + \[Delta]}, {-1, 1}}], 
        "Zoom View"}}], 


      {{\[Delta], \[Pi]/2, "Zoom Level"}, 10^-10, 
      2 \[Pi]}, {{x0, 0, "Center"}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]

(* this code looks prettier in a notebook! *)
```

The output looks like this:

[image: pan-zoom]

You could easily set up two more sliders to control the y-axis pan and zoom, like so:

```
    Clear[x0, y0];
    Manipulate[

     Grid[{{ListLinePlot[
         Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}],
         Epilog -> {{Blue, Opacity[0.1], 
            Rectangle[{x0 - \[Delta], y0 - \[Gamma]}, {x0 + \[Delta], 
              y0 + \[Gamma]}]}}], "Full Plot"},

       {ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, -2 \[Pi], 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/6}], 
         Axes -> False, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1, 
         Frame -> True, Filling -> Axis, 
         PlotRange -> {{x0 - \[Delta], x0 + \[Delta]}, {y0 - \[Gamma], 
            y0 + \[Gamma]}}], "Zoom View"}}],


     {{\[Delta], \[Pi]/2, "x Zoom Level"}, 10^-10, 2 \[Pi]},
     {{x0, 0, "x Center"}, -\[Pi], \[Pi]},
     {{\[Gamma], 0.5, "y Zoom Level"}, 10^-10, 1.1},
     {{y0, 0, "y Center"}, -1, 1}
     ]
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

You can easily fiddle the parameters to suit your aesthetic.